# SSH error: conq: unhandled exception

Tags: git, ssh, bitbucket, git-lfs

I'm trying to troubleshoot Bitbucket Git LFS working properly on my workstation, but failing on the remove server I want to deploy to. I'm getting `error: external filter git-lfs smudge -- %f failed 2` and using GIT_TRACE I've found the ssh command used is: `ssh git@bitbucket.org git-lfs-authenticate team/myrepo.git download`. When I run it locally, I get json with object location, but on the remote server I get such an error (both are Ubuntu 14.04):

```
..skipped..
Authenticated to bitbucket.org ([104.192.143.2]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LC_PAPER = en_AU.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LC_ADDRESS = en_AU.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LC_MONETARY = en_AU.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LC_NUMERIC = en_AU.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LC_TELEPHONE = en_AU.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LC_IDENTIFICATION = en_AU.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LC_MEASUREMENT = en_AU.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LC_CTYPE = en_US.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LC_TIME = en_AU.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LC_NAME = en_AU.UTF-8
debug1: Sending command: git-lfs-authenticate team/myrepo.git download
conq: unhandled exception
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
Transferred: sent 3936, received 1648 bytes, in 0.3 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 15183.1, received 6357.1
debug1: Exit status 1
```

So it authenticates fine (and `ssh -T` does too), but then this weird error **conq: unhandled exception**. What does it mean? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically this is an issue with bitbucket - deployment keys can't be used with git LFS, and it's not written anywhere. Their stupid software doesn't know better than to crash with "conq: unhandled exception" instead of something like, I don't know, "deployment keys can't be used with our git LFS".